# Duplicated generated primary key with SpringData and Postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity definition like (getters, setters not shown):

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

In JUnit I am trying to insert one new Entity. Before that JUnit I am loading few records to the Employee table. JUnit looks like below:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
    @Sql("/data/developers.sql")
    public class DeveloperRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private DeveloperRepository developerRepository;

    @Test
    public void shouldAddNewDeveloper() {
        // given
        Developer developer = new Developer();
        developer.setFirstName("Adam");
        developer.setLastName("AAA");
        developer.setExperienceLevel(ExperienceLevelEnum.SENIOR);


    developer.setProgrammingLanguages(Arrays.asList(ProgrammingLanguage.JAVA, ProgrammingLanguage.C_SHARP));

        // when
        developerRepository.save(developer);
        Iterable<Developer> developers = developerRepository.findAll();

        // then
        assertThat(developers.iterator().hasNext(), is(true));
         assertThat(developers.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown(), is(6l));
    }

}
```

In /deta/developers.sql I am inserting 5 new records so on the save of new entity I would expect to get id set to 6. But unfortunatelly SpringData (Hibernate) does not see exiting id values and tries to insert new record with id value 1 and the exception occurrs. When I change generation strategy to SEQUENCE it works. I am little bit surprised because it worked without any problems but when I tried to execute it once again it suddenly fail. If I try to execute it with IDENTITY strategy it fails as well. What is the problem here?

Comment: The fact that you are probably inserting data with pre-set keys instead of letting the database generate the keys.

Comment: So you mean that in the insert I should skip primary key and let it be generated by database?

Comment: Yes else the sequence (or whatever the database uses) won't be incremented correctly. It is that or reset the sequence to what you want it to start with.

Comment: The most strange thing is that it worked correctly but when I run code after some time (without updating any versions) it failed. When I left key generation to the database it should work with any strategy?

Comment: perhaps thats what the LOG is for, showing you the SQL invoked!

Comment: Try to use nextval('nameOfSequence') instead write directly primary key.

Comment: It works when I change entity definition to: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) or when I use nextval when inserting rows via sql script. Why Hibernate is not able to read current maximum value of column to insert the correct id?

Comment: You should use same id generator strategy on your own SQL as you use on hibernate.